# Удалить строки с кодировкой

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

Имеется большой файл, порой там попадаются такие строки, как удалить все строки с ASCII символами ?

```
123321╨╝╨░╤А╨╕╨╜╨░
123321╤А╨╡╨║╤Б
123321╤Б╨╡╤А╨│╨╡╨╣
123321╨▓╨╕╤В╨░
123321╨╡╨║╤Г
123321╨╣╤Ж╤Г╨║
123321╨╣╤Ж╤Г
123321╨╣╤Ж╤Г╤Г╤Ж╨╣
123321╨╝╨░╤И╨░╨┤╨╛
123321╨┐╨░╤И╨░1
123321╨╣╤К╤Д╤Н╤П.
123321╨╣╤Л╤Б╤П
123321╤Л╤Г
123321╨╝╨╕╨╜╤П╨╣
123321я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < filename > filename
```

Comment: tr: лишний операнд «610»
При удалении без уплотнения повторов можно задать две только одну таблицу.

Comment: в общем не понял как победить ошибку, сую ему файл а он ругается на операнды

Comment: `tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176'  < filename` что пишет?

Comment: вроде работает, правда удаляет просто эти символы а не строки с ними но тоже хорошо, спасибо

Comment: я неправильно понял. удалить можно так `grep -Ev "[a-zA-Z0-9]" filename > filename`